# DS2438 battery monitor: how to connect load

Tags: batteries, current-measurement

I am looking at the [datasheet for the Maxim DS2438](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS2438.pdf) battery monitor and am confused by this circuit diagram:

[image: Circuit diagram]

How would the load be connected?

If connected between battery + and circuit ground this would result in a voltage across the current sense resistor that is larger on Vsense- than on Vsense+. That does not seem right...

Comment: Is your question about a load other than the battery?

Comment: @Sparky256 Yes the load is whatever the battery that this curcuit monitors powers. I.e. the battery is the source. I am asking about the load.

Comment: I believe I have your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The charge current is through the battery (VDD), then Rsens, then to ground. Rf is just a ref for the VSENS- input. When charging VSENS+ is always positive compared to VSENS-. Please re-think the flow of the charge, from battery + to ground. Your synopsis is true-when the battery is under load. This paragraph from the DS2438 IC specs explains that this IC measures both charge and discharge current:
[The voltage across current sense resistor RSENS is measured by the ADC and the result is placed in the *Current Register in two’s complement format. The sign (S) of the result, indicating charge or discharge,* resides in the most significant bit of the Current Register, as shown in Table 3. See “Memory Map” in Figure 7 for the Current Register address location.]

Comment: Thanks. That seems so obvious now that you have explained it...